# How to hide the Logo of the whole website

Tags: css, web

I would like to set the webpage logo disappear by css display:none.

I already know how to open the element , for example , in the website www.kori.jp, i can find the div class .logo and able to put display:none in it.

But after reflesh or click other page, it appears again. I want to set it invisible for the whole website at the time I have my presentation.
How can i use and set the css in the chrome browse (or any browser which is more user friendly)

I need to present and show the website but cannot display the company information.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You cannot change the *actual* CSS on the server…? Perhaps of a local copy…? – Look into custom *user style sheets* in your browser…

Comment: Try this: `.logo { display: none !important; }`.

Comment: Use Ad Block extenstion and block Logo element.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this, but I'm not the one to question it. Editing elements in, for example, Chromes developer tools only store it temporarily and, since you're not *really* changing the CSS of the site, it is obvious it returns to its normal state when you refresh.

While it can and probably will break some functionality, what you could do is hit CTRL + U on a website to show its source, copy+paste everything from there into your own files somewhere locally, and change it that way. Remember to do this both for the .HTML and .CSS files though (and perhaps even .JS files if they exist on the site)!